# What's the difference between these two ways of creating an new ArrayList from existing List

Tags: java, arraylist

I came across this convoluted piece of code today:

```
public List<MyObject> toNewList(List<MyObject> someObjects) {

    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(someObjects.toArray(new MyObject[someObjects.size()])));

}
```

Is there any difference between the above code and the following snippet?

```
public List<MyObject> toNewList(List<MyObject> someObjects) {

    return new ArrayList<>(someObjects);

}
```

**Edit:** 
Looking back at the commit history provides an insight into devolving code. Here are each of the itterrations:

First commit:

```
return someObjects.toArray(new MyObject[0]);
```

Second commit:

```
return Arrays.asList(someObjects.toArray(new MyObject[0]));
```

Third commit:

```
return Arrays.asList(someObjects.toArray(new MyObject[someObjects.size()]));
```

Final commit:

```
return new ArrayList<MyObject>(Arrays.asList(someObjects.toArray(new MyObject[someObjects.size()])));
```

Definitely a good reminder to clean up messy code!

Comment: It could've been to work around a bug in some related code, or due to an automated code transformation that produced bad code, but my guess is that whoever wrote it just didn't understand what they were doing.

Comment: No. Just that second is clean.

Comment: `new MyObject[someObjects.size()]` Any typo errors here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no functional difference at all . Both call the [same constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) of ArrayList and the first is way redundant.

In first way you are doing a round trip of converting List to List which is completely unnecessarily. Second way is simple and clean.

Comment: There is a difference. The first one wastes CPU and memory, by first storing elements in a array (waste of memory), which means they get copied twice (waste of CPU).

Comment: @Andreas That is what I explained in my last paragraph.

Comment: I was commenting on your *"There is no difference at all"*, and clarifying the "cost" of what you simply call a "round trip".

Comment: @Andreas Should be fine now.